# AssertEqual failing when comparing two seemingly identical IndexErrors

Tags: python, unit-testing, dynamic-arrays

I have a DynamicArray class shown below. (I have only included relevant methods. The rest can be viewed from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-dynamic-array-in-python/)

```
import ctypes


class DynamicArray:
    '''
    Dynamic Array class
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0 # count number of elements
        self.capacity = 1 # default capacity
        self.A = self.make_array(self.capacity)

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Return number of elements in the array
        """
        return self.n

    def __getitem__(self,k):
        """
        Return element at k index
        """

        #Check if K index is out of bounds#
        if not 0 <= k < self.n:
            return IndexError('{} is out of bounds'.format(k))

        return self.A[k] #Retrieve from the array at index k#
```

Then I have another unit test file down below

```
from DynamicArray import DynamicArray
import unittest


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.a = DynamicArray()  # empty array

        self.b = DynamicArray()
        self.b.append(0)

        self.c = DynamicArray()
        self.c.append(0)
        self.c.append(1)

    def test_getitem(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.a.__getitem__(0),IndexError('0 is out of bounds'))
```

When I run the test I expect `self.a.__getitem__(0)` to throw `IndexError('0 is out of bounds')` and I can't see why the assertion fails? The only difference is that `self.a.__getitem__(0)` will yield `IndexError('{} is out of bounds'.format(0))`, which seems to me the same as `IndexError('0 is out of bounds')`

I tried running below code to see if the string by themselves were any different

```
    if '{} is out of bounds'.format(0) == '0 is out of bounds':
        print('str equal')
    if '{} is out of bounds'.format(0).__len__() == '0 is out of bounds'.__len__():
        print('len equal')
    if IndexError('{} is out of bounds'.format(0)) == IndexError('0 is out of bounds'):
        print('IndexError equal')
```

and confirmed that only the third if statement did not print

below is the photo of the console

[image]

Thanks in advance. Constructive criticisms and feedbacks are welcome.

Comment: `IndexError() == IndexError()` returns False on my system (Python 2.7) - I guess there's no `.__eq__()` method on Execeptions.  You'd need to do something like compare string representations of the exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions can't be conpared with `assertEqual`.

```
with self.assertRaises(IndexError, msg='0 is out of bounds'):
    self.a[0]
```

And Exceptions must be `raise`ed to be captured.
You're returning `IndexError`

```
raise IndexError('{} is out of bounds'.format(k))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises